# DataWeave move child key value into parent key

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have the following JSON as an input:

```
[
    {
        "abc: {
            "s": "123"
        },
        "pqr": {
            "s": "234"
        },
        "xyz": {
            "s": "345"
        }
    },
     {
        "abc: {
            "s": "456"
        },
        "pqr": {
            "s": "567"
        }
    }
]
```

My expected output is:

```
[
    {
        "abc: "123",
        "pqr": "234",
        "xyz": "345"
    },
     {
        "abc: "456",
        "pqr": "567",
        "xyz": null
    }
]
```

How can I achieve this in mule 4? Please suggest.

Note: The JSON object keys are dynamic. Here in the sample input, 3 keys are seen. But, as per input payload from other APIs, there can be more keys i.e. abc,def,pqr,mno,xyz etc.

Comment: Will the internal key always be "s" ?

Comment: Does the first record contain all keys always? Or do you have a separate list of all keys?

Comment: Hi @HarshankBansal, no, the internal key basically denotes 's' for string. It can be number,list etc. So, it wouldn't be always 's'.

Comment: Hi @aled, no the first record may or may not contain all the keys always. The keys are being passed in the payload body, like "abc,pqr,xyz,....,mno,def..".

Comment: Do you mean that the keys could be different for each record in the array and they are not all in a global location in the payload, but you need all keys in each record of the output?

Comment: @HarshankBansal please don't edit OP's invalid JSON to valid yourself unless OP mentions that they made that typo while posting the question (even in that case they should be the one to [edit]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapObject` to update each element of your array dynamically. If the JSON with the main value always has single field, you can get it using its index `[0]`.

For making sure to get all the keys in each object you will have to fetch all the keys initially and write the script around that.

```js
%dw 2.0
var allFields = payload flatMap keysOf($) distinctBy ($)
output application/json  
---
payload map ((nestedJson) -> 
    allFields reduce ((field, acc = {}) -> {
        (acc),
        (field): (nestedJson[field])[0]
    })
)
```

Comment: Hi Harshank, first of all, thanks for your solution. The internal key basically denotes 's' for string. It can be number, list etc. So, it wouldn't be always 's', eliminating the fact that we can't do '(key): valueWithS.s'. That said, the key 'xyz' that is present in the first record, is not present in the second record of the input. So, in the second record of the output, it should appear as 'xyz:null' which is not present in the solution you provided.

[
  {
    "abc": "123",
    "pqr": "234",
    "xyz": "345"
  },
  {
    "abc": "456",
    "pqr": "567"
  }
]

Comment: okay. so it is not always "s" but is it aways going to be a single key?

Comment: This is working as expected! Thank you so much for your solution and help.